# Scraping tables with Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, datatables

I'm learning **Python**, and I don`t have much experience. I need scrape tables from a website but the code that I wrote doesn't work.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
import csv
import ssl
head = []
headers = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = "https://www.bkt-tires.com/es/pattern/fs-216"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('th', class_="tableheader")

for tag in tags:
    if not tag.text in head:
        head.append(tag.text)

data_content = []
table = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed')
rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cells) > 1:
        data_info = [cell.text.strip('\n') for cell in cells]
```

Then I got this error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9:
>   UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new
>   attribute name - see
>   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
>   if **name** == '**main**':

Somebody help me please!!!

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: That is a warning. It means you are creating a column in dataframe like df.a=[1,2..] somewhere in your code, perhaps from the data that is scraped.
Instead, you can try df['a']=[1,2..]

Comment: Is there some more code you are not sharing here? The error/warning you describe here is related to pandas, but aside from importing it in your script, you don't seem to use it at all here.

Comment: do you want the load pressure table too? or just the main table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting that error as the code you are showing doesn't use Pandas. But doesn't mean you shouldn't. I used pandas `.read_html()` here, as it uses beautifulsoup under the hood to parse `<table>` tags. I don't know if you want the sub-tables, but this will get you the main table, and I added a part to see the sub-tables as well.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

import ssl
head = []
headers = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = "https://www.bkt-tires.com/es/pattern/fs-216"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


# I'm keeping this because it does a better job of pullin the headers than pandas did
tags = soup.find_all('th', class_="tableheader")
for tag in tags:
    if not tag.text in head:
        head.append(tag.text)




# Takes the html and parses the <table> tag 
# This will return a list of dataframes
dfs = pd.read_html(html)

# Grabs the dataframe from that list, in index position 0
# The other index postions are the sub tables
df = dfs[0]


# Here we will clean the data
# Drop the "messy" rows
df = df[~df.iloc[:,0].str.contains("mph")]
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df.columns = head + ['']
df = df.dropna(subset=['TRA Code']).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df.to_string())

df.to_csv(“file.csv”, index=False)


for idx, temp_df in enumerate(dfs):
    print (df.iloc[idx-1,:].to_string() + '\n\n' + temp_df.to_string() + '\n'+'*'*50 + '\n'+'*'*50)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
             Size        Version   US Code            LI/SS  PR            RIM REC    SW    OD   SLR     RC Type TMPH              ECE TRA Code
0       18.4 - 26  ARAMID BELTED  94027552              NaN  10            DW 16 A  18.4  58.1  26.9  174.5   TT    0  E11-106R-003404     LS-2
1       18.4 - 26   STEEL BELTED  94027996              NaN  10            DW 16 A  18.4  58.1  26.9  174.5   TT    0  E11-106R-003637     LS-2
2       23.1 - 26  ARAMID BELTED  94026333              NaN  10  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003649     LS-2
3       23.1 - 26   STEEL BELTED  94028108              NaN  10  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003650     LS-2
4       23.1 - 26  ARAMID BELTED  94026562              NaN  12  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003405     LS-2
5       23.1 - 26   STEEL BELTED  94028603              NaN  12  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003651     LS-2
6       23.1 - 26  ARAMID BELTED  94031825              NaN  14  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003658     LS-2
7       23.1 - 26   STEEL BELTED  94029457              NaN  14  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003411     LS-2
8       23.1 - 26  ARAMID BELTED  94026685              NaN  16  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003660     LS-2
9       23.1 - 26   STEEL BELTED  94031795              NaN  16  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT    0  E11-106R-003661     LS-2
10      23.1 - 26   STEEL BELTED  94040391              NaN  16  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TL    0  E11-106R-003662     LS-2
11      23.1 - 26            NaN  94054848  174 A2 / 165 A6  20  DW 20 A ; DW 20 B  23.1  63.6  28.6  188.2   TT  NaN  E11-106R-004635     LS-2
12       28L - 26   STEEL BELTED  94029334              NaN  14  DW 25 A ; DW 25 B  28.3  65.4  29.2  193.4   TL    0  E11-106R-003413     LS-2
13       28L - 26   STEEL BELTED  94031887              NaN  18  DW 25 A ; DW 25 B  28.3  65.4  29.2  193.4   TL  NaN  E11-106R-003425     LS-2
14       28L - 26   STEEL BELTED  94049608              NaN  20  DW 25 A ; DW 25 B  28.3  65.4  29.2  193.4   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
15       28L - 26   STEEL BELTED  94057856              NaN  26  DW 25 A ; DW 25 B  28.3  65.4  29.2  193.4   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
16      18.4 - 30  ARAMID BELTED  94027712              NaN  10            DW 16 A  18.4  62.1  28.5  186.5   TT    0  E11-106R-003652     LS-2
17      18.4 - 30   STEEL BELTED  94028115              NaN  10            DW 16 A  18.4  62.1  28.5  186.5   TT    0  E11-106R-003638     LS-2
18      18.4 - 30   STEEL BELTED  94029969              NaN  14            DW 16 A  18.4  62.1  28.5  186.5   TT  NaN  E11-106R-004644     LS-2
19     24. 5 - 32   STEEL BELTED  94033669              NaN  16              DH 21  24.5  72.1  32.9  214.8   TL    0  E11-106R-003421     LS-2
20      24.5 - 32  ARAMID BELTED  94054855  182 A2 / 172 A6  24              DH 21  24.5  72.1  32.9  214.8   TL  NaN  E11-106R-004636     LS-2
21     30.5L - 32  ARAMID BELTED  94027736              NaN  16              DH 27  30.5  72.7  32.8  215.2   TL    0  E11-106R-003424     LS-2
22     30.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94027620              NaN  16              DH 27  30.5  72.7  32.8  215.2   TL  NaN  E11-106R-003426     LS-2
23     30.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94028900              NaN  20              DH 27  30.5  72.7  32.8  215.2   TL  NaN  E11-106R-003439     LS-2
24     30.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94044313              NaN  26              DH 27  30.5  72.7  32.8  215.2   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
25     30.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94048397              NaN  32              DH 27  30.5  72.7  32.8  215.2   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
26  DH 35.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94043729              NaN  20              DH 31  35.7  79.2  35.9  235.9   TL  NaN  E11-106R-003349     LS-2
27  DH 35.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94062713              NaN  24              DH 31  35.7  79.2  35.9  235.9   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
28  DH 35.5L - 32   STEEL BELTED  94048380              NaN  30              DH 31  35.7  79.2  35.9  235.9   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
29      18.4 - 34  ARAMID BELTED  94027743              NaN  10            DW 16 A  18.4  66.1  30.2  198.5   TT    0  E11-106R-003653     LS-2
30      18.4 - 34   STEEL BELTED  94028122              NaN  10            DW 16 A  18.4  66.1  30.2  198.5   TT    0  E11-106R-004560     LS-2
31      18.4 - 34  ARAMID BELTED  94029532              NaN  14            DW 16 A  18.4  66.1  30.2  198.5   TL  NaN              NaN     LS-2
32      18.4 - 34   STEEL BELTED  94029297              NaN  14            DW 16 A  18.4  66.1  30.2  198.5   TL    0  E11-106R-003401     LS-2
```

Comment: Awesome... thanks a lot! Yes, I need the sub-tables too, and then I need grabe them in a csv file. Though, wen I run your code, apear this error: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 14 elements, new values have 13 elements"

Comment: what version of pandas and beautifulsoup do you have installed?

Comment: Pandas: '0.25.3' and BeautifulSoup4 (4.8.1)

Comment: I have pandas 0.24.2 and bs4 (4.6.3); That might be the difference. Just seems like it keeping 14 columns, when I'm dropping the last column that is all nulls. I adjusted the code, see if it works now

Comment: Yes! now it works! Thank you so much! Could you help me to export the df to a csv file?

Comment: Simple 1 line with pandas. I added it to the bottom of the code. Be sure to accept the solution

Answer (score 3):

Check out the script below. I suppose it will fetch you the tabular content from that page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://www.bkt-tires.com/es/pattern/fs-216"

res = requests.get(url,verify=False,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select('table#codes tr[id]'):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in row.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Pandas version. You're importing Pandas, but not using it in this snippet. If you're using it somewhere else in the code, can you add that portion? Otherwise, try not importing pandas.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've been modified the code several times and I'm to confused now... efectively i'm not using pandas... but if I eliminate that part of code, it doesn't change the error...

Comment: @PaulaVallejo _I’ve been modified the code several times_ Since you’ve asked the question? If so, please add any information as an edit.